# What Similarity of Matrices really mean?

Tags: matrices, soft-question

If matrices are similar then what in layman language it would imply? Are there some properties of matrices which we would expect to be similar?

Answer (score 4):

Consider a linear map $T:V\rightarrow W$ where $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces. Given a basis $\alpha$ of $V$ and a basis $\beta$ of $W$, one can find the matrix $[T]_{\alpha}^{\beta}$ of the linear map $T$ w.r.t. $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Now if $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$ are other bases, then you can represent $T$ by the matrix $[T]_{\alpha'}^{\beta'}$. Now obviously you expect some kind of relation between these two matrices since they represent the same linear map. And indeed, these two matrices are similar.

Conversely, any matrix represents a linear map, two similar matrices represent the same linear map w.r.t. different bases.

You expect that properties that you can define for linear maps are preserved under similar matrices, for example the trace (for square matrices) is preserved.